# Block UI after successful of fields verification

Tags: forms, jsf, primefaces, blockui

I use a JSF 2.2 with a Primefaces 5.3. I have to create a form which will be work like this:

After pushing a button:

- If all required fields are filled in, the page is blocked (due to the sending of data to the database) as long as the data are sent.
- If one of the required fields aren't filled in, the page isn't blocked.

Could you tell me how can I do it?

This is a xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile"
      xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
    <h:head></h:head>
    <h:body id="page">

        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewAction action="#{loginController.start()}" />
        </f:metadata>  

        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />

        <h:form>
            <p:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" styleClass="ui-noborder" columnClasses="rightalign,leftalign">                      
                <p:outputLabel for="databaseName" value="Database name:" />
                <p:inputText id="databaseName" required="true" value="#{userDatabase.name}" />
                <p:outputLabel for="databaseFile" value="File:" />
                <p:fileUpload id="databaseFile" required="true" fileLimit="1" update="file messages" fileUploadListener="#{dataController.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" sizeLimit="1000000000" uploadLabel="Upload" cancelLabel="Delete" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|binetflow)$/" />              
                <h:panelGroup />
                <h:outputText id="fileDescription" value="#{dataController.fileName}" />                        
                <p:commandButton id="buttonSend" value="Send" update="messages" action="#{dataController.send()}" />                        
            </p:panelGrid>

            <p:blockUI block="page" trigger="buttonSend">
                Sending of the data...              
            </p:blockUI>            

        </h:form>

    </h:body>   
</html>
```

This is a CDI bean:

```
package com.system.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;

import com.system.model.UserDatabase;
import com.system.service.DataService;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class DataController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1383572529241805730L;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event){
        uploadFile=event.getFile(); 

        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Successful", event.getFile().getFileName() + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);        
    }

    public String getFileName(){

        if(uploadFile==null) return "";
        else return uploadFile.getFileName();               
    }

    public void send(){

        if(uploadFile==null){

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "The file isn't uploaded", "You should upload a file"));
        }
        else{

            //Sending the data to the database... (tha page should be blocked)

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //After successful of sending the data, the page should be unlocked.

            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "The data has been added.", ""));           
        }
    }

    @Named
    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    private UserDatabase userDatabase=new UserDatabase();  

    @Inject
    private DataService dataService;

    @Inject
    private Logger log;

    private UploadedFile uploadFile;
}
```

Of course the above code it works but the page is blocked every time when I push the button (even if the fields aren't filled in). I think I should use a `widgetVar` istead of a `trigger` in a `p:blockUI` component but I don't know how and maybe I'm wrong. The best way for me would be if I could block/unlock the page from the `send` method in the CDI bean but I don't know if it's possible and apart from that - this isn't necessary. Each way will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. These are steps which I did:

1. I used the `widgetVar` attribute istead of the `trigger` in the blockUI component:

   ```
   <p:blockUI block="page" widgetVar="widgetBlock">
       Sending of the data...          
   </p:blockUI>
   ```
2. I created my own validation method in the `DataController` bean:

   ```
   public boolean isValidation(){

       if(uploadFile==null || userTable.getName()==null || userTable.getName().trim().equals("")) return false;
       else return true;
   }
   ```
3. I added the `onstart` (where I call to my validation method and I block the page if I get `true`) and the `oncomplete` (where I unlock the page) attributes for the commandButton:

   ```
   <p:commandButton id="buttonSend" value="Send" action="#{dataController.send()}" update="messages" 
                    onstart="if(#{dataController.validation}){PF('widgetBlock').show()}" 
                    oncomplete="PF('widgetBlock').hide()" />
   ```
4. I put commandButton `id` to the `update` attribute in the fileupload component. Apart from that I deleted the `require` attribute from the fileupload:

   ```
   <p:fileUpload id="file" 
                 fileLimit="1"
                 update="buttonSend fileDescription messages" 
                 fileUploadListener="#{dataController.handleFileUpload}" 
                 mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" sizeLimit="1000000000" 
                 uploadLabel="Upload" cancelLabel="Delete" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(txt|binetflow)$/" />               
   <h:panelGroup />
   ```
5. I deleted the `require` attribute from inputtext component as well and added the `<p:ajax>` tag (I deleted this attribute because the `<p:ajax>` tag wouldn't work with this attribute like I want, look at my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184337/keyup-event-for-inputtext-and-removing-content-of-the-inputtext)):

   ```
   <p:inputText  id="tableName" value="#{userTable.name}" >
       <p:ajax event="keyup" update="buttonSend" />                    
   </p:inputText>
   ```
6. At the end I moved the validation of the fields from the xhtml page to my `send` method in `DataController` bean:

   ```
   public void send(){             

       boolean validation=true;

       if(userTable.getName()==null || userTable.getName().trim().equals("")){

           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "The name field isn't filled", "You should fill this field"));

           validation=false;
       }

       if(uploadFile==null){

           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "The file isn't uploaded", "You should upload a file"));

           validation=false;
       }       

       if(validation){

           //Sending the data to the database... (tha page is blocked)

           try {
               Thread.sleep(5000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           //After successful of sending the data, the page is unlocked.

           FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "The data has been added.", ""));           
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the validation failed like this

just attach rendered="#{facesContext.validationFailed}" to your blockui and also update it when the form gets submitted

Comment: I tried to implement your idea but it doesn't work or I did something wrong. I added `id` and `rendered` for blockUI component. Apart from that I added blockUI 'id' to 'update' attribute in commandButton component as well. After that the blockUI component doesn't work at all. Have you got any idea why? First of all I noticed that when I used a content assist in eclipse for rendered=#{}, the eclipse doesn't show me any facesContext object. Maybe I've forgotten add something?

Comment: content assist doesnt work for expression language afaik

and did you put inside " " ? in your comment you have it without them

if that doesnt work you could try giving adding a widget var to your blockui and in the onstart  or onclick of your commandbutton something like if(#{facesContext.validationFailed()}){widget.hide();}

Comment: Of course I put `#{}` inside " " in my code. I forgot about it in comment. Unfortunately the second idea it doesn't work either. In my opinion the problem is `#{facesContext.validationFailed()}`. I checked the return value and in each case I still get `false`. Have you got any idea why?

Comment: BTW: Based on your second idea - I found a solution but I found a problem as well for the balance. I created my own validation method (which returns `true` or `false`) in `DataController` bean and used it istead of `facesContext.validationFailed()`. For first idea - it still doesn't work but for modified second idea - it works (almost). I used `widgetVar` istead of `trigger` in the blockUI. Then I added `onstart` (where I call to my validation method and I block the page if I get `true`) and `oncomplete` (where I unlock the page) attributes for the commandButton.

Comment: At the end I added a `update` attribute to the fileupload component and I put commandButton `id` there. Now it works but not at all. I found the problem associated with this solution: In my own validation method - I can check the fileupload component (like `if(uploadFile==null)`) because I use `update` attribute for fileupload as I said before but I can't check the value from inputtext component because it isn't available in bean as long as I push button.

Comment: So at the moment the page isn't blocked if the file isn't upload (great!) but the page is blocked when the require inputtext component is empty (wrong). Do you know any way for get access to the value from inputtext component in bean (the value is stored in `userDatabase` object: `userDatabase.name` as you can see in my code at post) before pushing button?